# I need an implementation of java.time.LocalTime Converter

Tags: java, jpa, time

I'm using a LocalDate Converter, and now I need to use LocalTime also, Can anybody show me the code for the LocalTime JPA Converter, Thanks.

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class LocalDateDateConverter implements AttributeConverter<LocalDate, Date> {

    @Override
    public Date convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalDate locDate) {
        return (locDate == null ? null : Date.valueOf(locDate));
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDate convertToEntityAttribute(Date sqlDate) {
        return (sqlDate == null ? null : sqlDate.toLocalDate());
    }
}
```

Comment: "Give me the code" type questions are generally not very well received here. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Here is The answer: 
 public Time convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalTime locTime) {
  return (locTime == null ? null : Time.valueOf(locTime));
 }

 
 public LocalTime convertToEntityAttribute(Time time) {
  return (time == null ? null : time.toLocalTime());
 }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you need to convert to and from `java.sql.Time` for the database. Look at the methods [`valueOf(LocalTime)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Time.html#valueOf-java.time.LocalTime-) and [`toLocalTime()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Time.html#toLocalTime--) in that class. Your code will be quite similar to the code you already have. Edit: I mean the code in the question; only after writing the answer I became aware that someone else had edited it in there.

Comment: Thanks, I find the same answer you suggest in a book